# problemas con el certificado ssl de xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.forms

Tengo este problema con el certificado de una web api en `POST` y `GET`.
Espero me puedan ayudar saludos.

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. ---> Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. ---> Java.Security.Cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. ---> Java.Security.Cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: encontré la solución para este problema , quien necesite ayuda solo comentar.

Comment: Tengo este problema cómo puedo solucionarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es relacionado a los certificados.

> **CertPathValidatorException** : Una excepción que indica uno de los
>   diversos problemas encontrados al validar una ruta de certificación.
>   Una excepción **CertPathValidatorException** también puede incluir la ruta de certificación que se estaba validando cuando se lanzó la excepción, el índice del certificado en la  ruta de certificación que causó la excepción y la razón que causó la falla.

El problema no se genera por la aplicación si no por el servidor que aloja tu Web Service, no tiene un certificado válido o este se encuentra mal configurado. Puedes usar https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ para analizar el sitio y obtener información que te ayudará a solucionar el problema.

Otra forma de evitar este error es únicamente usar http:// para no requerir ningún certificado. Aunque en realidad lo recomendable es usar urls cifrados usando https://

Puedes usar https://www.digicert.com/help/ para verificar el estatus de tu certificado, escribiendo su dominio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]